# Laravel4: Checkbox

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

I have to define a checkbox within a Laravel 4 app.
But at the same time it is a Bootstrap 2.3.1 site,
and i need to pass also Input::old
How can i do it?

This is how it was in html:

```
            <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="extraBed" value="extra" />
               <span class="blue"><strong class="blue"><span><i class="icon-plus"></i></span> Extra bed</span>
            </label>
```

This is how i have tried to write in Laravel4:

```
            <label class="checkbox">            
            {{ Form::checkbox('extraBed', Input::old('extraBed'), 'extra' }}
               <span class="blue"><strong class="blue"><span><i class="icon-plus"></i></span> Extra bed</span>
            </label>
```

But i get this error:

syntax error, unexpected ';'

Someone knows how can i do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a closing tag.

```
{{ Form::checkbox('extraBed', Input::old('extraBed'), 'extra') }}
```

see if that helps!

Comment: Well closing parenthesis to be exact.

Comment: Oh my God what a shame! :) 
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, after one minute i will be allow to check the answer as correct!

Comment: If you want i have made a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904059/laravel4-how-to-pass-datepicker-into-a-form

Comment: Hei man! If you are not completely bored by these problems, here is the last question about my form :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904984/laravel4-form-with-image-picker