# Laravel4: How to pass Datepicker into a form?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, laravel, laravel-4

For proper validation i have to rewrite into Laravel4 all the form fields i have,
the main reason is that i need to add Input::old to all the fields.

So far it went good with text, textarea and checkbox.
But i don't know how to deal with the calendar data.
It is Datepicker, a pretty nice JQuery plugin: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker
There are two fields, one for the arrival, the other for the outgoing.

This is the html properly working:

```
            <div class="input-append date ">
              <p>
                <label><span><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span> Arrival Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="arrival" class="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="checkin" placeholder="click here"/> 
              </p>
            </div>

            <div class="input-append date"> 
              <p>
                <label><span><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span> Outgoing Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="outgoing" class="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="checkout" placeholder="click here"/>
              </p>                
            </div>
```

How can i write this in Laravel4?
If for some reason is not possible is not a big deal, but is very important that i can add the Input::old('arrival') and Input::old('outgoing').
Someone knows how can i do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: to be sure, you just need to be able to pass in the class attribute right?

Comment: The goal is that if there are some errors in the form, the fields that was already filled up will remain filled up.
So what i need is somehow add Input::old('') to that two Datepicker fields.

Comment: Are you creating the two inputs with blade? If so can you edit and post that code?

Comment: No no. At the moment the two fields are only in html.

Comment: Well, if I understand how Input::old() works (never used it) I would say that maybe adding value="<?php echo Input:old()?>" might work?

Comment: Hei man, second correct answer in a row!! Thank you!
It worked with:  value="{{ Input::old('arrival') }}"
If you write the answer i will check as correct.

Comment: Also for this I think you could most likely write a Form macro that will make this easier in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the input as:

```
value="{{ Input::old('inputName') }}"
```

it should work as we've discovered!

Comment: with blade syntax will be:  value="{{ Input::old('inputName') }}"

Comment: Good point! I was kind of thinking on the idea that the whole input wasn't with blade so I should use normal PHP! I'll update it!