# Laravel4: Form with image-picker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, laravel, laravel-4

In a site working with Bootstrap + Laravel4.
In a form, there are some images that the user can click to select it.
It is done with a nice JQuery plugin: http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

Right now it is written in html and it is working:

```
            <label><span><i class="icon-check"></i></span> Click on a room to select it</label>
          <select name="rooms[]" multiple="multiple" class="image-picker show-html">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option name="1room" data-img-src="assets/img/rooms/singleRoom.jpg" value="Single room">Single room</option>
              <option name="2room" data-img-src="assets/img/rooms/2room.jpg" value="Double room">Double room</option>
          </select>
```

I do not need to rewrite all these markups in Laravel4.
But i need one thing: I have to add to Input::old('inputName') to retain the values in case of validation errors.
That is very important.
I have tried doing this: 
- set value of the single options to: {{ 'Single room', Input::old('1room') }}
- set the value of the select to {{ Input::old('rooms[]') }}
But none of them is working.
It gives no errors, but the original value is not retained.

Someone knows how can i do it?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

Printing out the value of Input::old() at the top of the page, the value for rooms are actually retained:

```
array (size=8)
  'rooms' => 
  array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Single room' (length=11)
  1 => string 'Double room' (length=11)
 'arrival' => string '13/11/2013' (length=10)
 'outgoing' => string '11/11/2013' (length=10)
 'name' => string 'name' (length=4)
 'email' => string 'email' (length=5)
 'phone' => string '9999999999' (length=10)
 'message' => string 'gjhgjghj' (length=8)
 'submit' => string '' (length=0)
```

The point is how to display them in the form. Precisely how to select some images based on the values contained in that array.

**EDIT2:**

This is how to understand which options of the select are selected, thanks to @Samuraisoulification:

```
          <?php  
              if (isset(Input::old()['rooms']))
              {

               for($i = 0 , $input = Input::old()['rooms'] , $c = count($input) ; $i < $c ; $i++)
               {
                 if($input[$i] == "Single room")
                 {
                      echo "Single room selected";
                 }

                 if($input[$i] == "Double room")
                 {
                      echo "Double room selected";
                 }
               }
              }
          ?>
```

Comment: Maybe the JQuery plug in is changing something when it sends the data? Also why is it rooms[] ? not just rooms

Comment: Actually did not remember why there was rooms[].. i change it with 'rooms' and the html works in any case.
But anyway {{ Input::old('rooms') }} is not working

Comment: try to just output what Input::old() gets you. Like just at the top of the page, try it. Do you get anything?

Comment: I think it is a good idea to verify what contains it! But how can i do it exactly? I try to write this in the controller:                  $old = Input::old(); dd($old);  But is not working, it gives an empty array. And id not true since the others input::old are inserted correctly in the form, is only for 'rooms' that is not working, so it must contain something, it is me that i am not checking correctly Input::old(). How can i check this value properly?

Comment: IF it's not a live site at the moment I would say just at the top of the page type Input Old: {{ Input::old() }} <br> and see what comes out.

Comment: What did you select when you sent it? And can you select more than one option? Also do you have other elements on this page? Seemed like more than just that select was outputted. More info so I can interpret the data please!

Comment: Yes, DatePicker allow multiple selection. The fields output with Input::old are all the fields i have on the form: name - email - phone - rooms - arrival - outgoing - extraBed (checkbox) - message.

Comment: And you picked which ones in the test case Input::old above? Did you select both room styles?

Comment: Yes in the example i have selected the both rooms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very inelegant solution, but should work if I'm correct. In the option tags add:

```
    <?php  
        for($i = 0 , $input = Input::old()['rooms'] , $c = count($input) ; $i < $c ; $i++){
           if($input[$i] == "<select option's name>"){
                echo "selected";
           }
         }
?>
```

Note that the $input and $c are not in the comparison part so they will only be evaluated once, saving you a small amount of time(like page load time) on all the options you may have later. This is an inelegant solution, but since you allow multiple values, I think this is the only way to do it. Give a whirl and let me know if it has issues! Also be sure to put this code in each opening  tag!

Also I would say condensing this all to one line would look better too.

Lastly, I think because options are different than inputs, the `value=="{{Input::old}}"` doesn't work, becasue in order for it to be selected you have to say selected on it. Also be sure to comment this hack for future reference.

Comment: Thanks for the effort!
The logic is working since if the input is "Single room" then is echo'selected' otherwise no. Now the point is how to select a specific option, no?

Comment: Edit the question now to show me what you have coded, and what the output is please!

Comment: I have edited the question. The output is the echo value, if that option is selected.

Comment: Wait so for if($input[$i] == "Single room")
                 {
                      echo "Single room selected";
                 }
you actually echo out "Single room selected" not just selected?

Comment: Yes for the debug yes. When there was 'selected' it echo out 'selected'.

Comment: Can I see the html output as well? Not in the debug mode.

Comment: the html is exactly: Single room selected

Comment: But I want the whole select. Starting from the <select

Comment: I want to see it because I'm concerned something else weird is happening because if you add select to the ones that need it, it should work as per this fiddle I made http://jsfiddle.net/5UbzN/

Comment: You are a genius!! I did not understand that i had to put it right after the option (shame on me) it was only up the whole select. 
Putting it right after <option it works smoothly and after validation the image is still selected!
Thank you very much for all this effort!
Ah you can also specify in the reply that had to be putted right after <option

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be right after option, just somewhere in the opening tag of it, but I'll edit that!

Comment: Also, I"m gonna sleep so if you have any more Laravel problems, ask me tomorrow. :P